# how to do search in the same page?

Tags: php, mysql

1) this my search form

search.html :

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="query" />
<input type="hidden" name="searching"> 
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

2) All of my search process is handled and will be shown on process.php.

process.php :

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("*****","*****","*****");   
if (!connection) {
    die ("Please reload page. Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
   }

    // Select a databse to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db("*****",$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Please reload page. Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
   }

if (isset($_POST["searching"])) {
    /*call search process*/ 
    dosearch();
   }   

function doSearch(){
  $keyword = $_POST("query");
  $search = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%'";
  $result = mysql_query($search) or die('query did not work');
   While($result_arr = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
    { 
     echo $result_arr['name']; 
     echo " ";
     echo "<br>"; 
     echo "<br>"; 
    }
  }
?>
```

3)How to show the search result at page "search.html" and how to combine it into one same page?

Comment: If you need .html (or you don't want to refresh page) - ajax, if you don't need .html -> simple turn file to .php, add code, and leave 'action' value empty.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do??

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create search.php instead of search.html.

you may try using php sessions. they are very helpful.

you can save whatever variable you want to transfer from "process.php" to "search.php" in the $_SESSION array and then use them in search.php. for example :

in process.php

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['a']=$result_arr['name'];
?>
```

then in search.php

```
<?php session_start();
echo $_SESSION['a'];
?>
```